# pyspark:syntax error with multiple operation in one map function

Tags: python, lambda, apache-spark, pyspark

I am adding an additional operation in my pyspark map function.

The original function is:

```
results = input.map(lambda row:process_myData(row))
```

which works fine. Then I tried to add an additional operation like below:

```
results = input.map{lambda row:
            row1 = row.replace("abc","def")
            process_myData(row1)}
```

Then I got the syntax error below:

```
    results = input.map{lambda row:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What did I do wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't read [the manual](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#lambda). Lambda expression is an expression and a such cannot contain statements. If you're not convinced you can trace possible expansions starting from:

```
lambda_expr        ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list]: expression
lambda_expr_nocond ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list]: expression_nocond
```

If you want to use statements you have to use standard function:

```
def f(row):
    row1 = row.replace("abc","def")
    return process_myData(row1)

input.map(f)
```

although here a simple composition would be enough:

```
input.map(lambda row: process_myData(row.replace("abc","def")))
```

Comment: you mean: input.map(lambda row: f(row)) , not just input.map(f), right? thanks.

Comment: No, I mean exactly `input.map(f)` :) `RDD.map` takes a function as the first argument and this is exactly what it gets. There is no reason to wrap it further with an anonymous function.

Comment: so lambda doesn't need to be specified explicitly? Then can the original input.map(lambda row:process_myData(row))  be simplified to input.map(process_myData) ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you can do. Typically there is no reason to use lambdas if the function you use expects only a single argument (it also covers methods which take only `self`)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
results = input.map(lambda row: process_myData(row.replace("abc","def")))
```

But you should not use lambda when there are more than one instructions. Use functions.

And you also use different type of brackets :/.

Answer (score 1):

You get invalid syntax because you are using braces instead of parentheses.  Even if you fix that, however, you will get another syntax error.  A lambda expression is `lambda args: return_value`.  You cannot have assignments in a lambda expression.  To do that, you need to define your own function.  You don't need to define `row1`, however.  You can just put it right into `process_myData`: `lambda row: process_myData(row.replace("abc", "def"))`